# A question about Laplace trafsform

Tags: laplace-transform

We know Laplace transform as the following: $$\int_0^\infty f(t) \cdot e^{-st} dt$$
In here, parameter $s$ is a complex?

Comment: Yes, $s$ is usually taken to be a complex number.

Comment: It can be also real, but usually complex, right? ( Real number set is already subset of complex numbers set)

Comment: Real numbers are also complex numbers.  For example, $2 = 2 + 0i$.

Comment: That is correct.